# Can't open unity projects on new laptop. 'No valid unity editor license found. Please activate your license.'

Tags: unity-game-engine, hub

*Hi, I sold my PC with hard reset, so no unity on that, I have another laptop with unity on it, signed into the same account. I bought this laptop, installed windows 11, and can't get Unity to work.* 
 **Things I've tried:**

- Logged out on everything except this laptop now.
- Deleted C:\ProgramData\Unity\Unity_lic.ulf and reopened unity

Any ideas why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Return the license on this. Go to unity website. Delete your pro license from all machines. Listed. Now try again.

Comment: Thanks, the error disappeared, Unity loading image appears, and after 5 sec, it disappears.

Comment: Try the @BugFinder answer in beta channel, you can change it in the advanced tab. Don´t forget update the app.

Comment: Downloaded a beta editor version, and it opened, thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, steps I took:

- returned the license, and deleted my pro versions, as @BugFinder
  said.
- downloaded the newest beta editor version, opened my project with
  that as @Juxant said.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had Unity Hub installed both via [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/home) and manually. The Flatpak had the license showing, but the manual one didn't. I had to open the manual install, re-add my license, and then it started working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, updating the Unity hub to the latest version solved the issue.